# Access policy is not getting triggered for Parent role

Tags: identity, role, identity-management, oim, identitymanager

I was working on parent child roles in OIM. Suppose Role A is parent and Role B is child .Role A has access policy A attached to it and similarly Role B has access policy B attached to it. Now when i assign Role B(child role) to user Role A automatically gets provisioned to user along with Role B (expected behavior).

Role B related entitlements getting assigned but Role A entitlements are not getting assigned (even the access policy not getting triggered). If I assign Role A to any user its corresponding entitlements are getting assigned , so no problem in access policy.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a bug reported and applying patch should resolve this issue. Check oracle support for the patch information.